# Find a certain value and copy that into another data.frame

Tags: r, compare, dataframe

I have a data.frame in which I want to find the first change in either column D or E. After finding this value, I want to copy it into a new `data.frame` with less rows.

Here's an example:

[image: Picture of data.frame]

```
ID  Group   Subgroup    D          E  
 1  1   A   2   1.25     1.10
 2  2   A   2   1.25     1.10
 3  3   A   2   1.25     1.10
 4  4   A   2   1.30     1.10
 5  5   A   2   1.32     1.10
 6  6   A   2   1.32     1.10
 7  7   B   4   3.20     2.42
 8  8   B   4   3.20     2.42
 9  9   B   4   3.20     2.49
10  10  B   4   3.20     2.53
11  11  B   4   3.20     2.57
12  12  B   4   3.20     2.57
13  13  C   3   2.10     1.80
14  14  C   3   2.10     1.80
15  15  C   3   2.10     1.87
16  16  C   3   2.10     1.90
17  17  A   5   3.30     2.50
18  18  A   5   3.30     2.50
19  19  A   5   3.40     2.50
```

I would want to detect the change per Group and Subgroup, so for A.2 at D 1.3 [4,4] ; for B.4 at E 2.49 [9,5] ; for C.3 at E 1.87 [15,5] and for A.5 at D 3.4 [19,4]

Then I would want those values to be in a new `data.frame` with less rows that just display the values of interest.

In this case this would be 4x1 with rows A.2, B.4, C.3 and A.5 and a column called "reactionT" where the values from either D or E are stored. Something like this:

[image: Picture of result]

```
ID         Group      Subgroup   reationT  
1   1   A   2   1.30
2   2   B   4   2.49
3   3   C   3   1.87
4   4   A   5   3.40
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear how you would want to treat the possible scenario that a change happens at the same time in column "D" and column "E", so I've left those as separate columns.

Here's one possible approach:

```
library(data.table)
as.data.table(df1)[, list(D = D[diff(c(D[1], D)) > 0][1], 
                          E = E[diff(c(E[1], E)) > 0][1]), 
                   by = list(Group, Subgroup)]
#    Group Subgroup   D    E
# 1:     A        2 1.3   NA
# 2:     B        4  NA 2.49
# 3:     C        3  NA 1.87
# 4:     A        5 3.4   NA
```

If you know that there will never be a value in columns "D" and "E" at the same time in this collapsed form, I suppose you could use `sum` with `na.rm = TRUE` to collapse those columns into 1.